# How to clone scnnode with different instance?

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit, scnnode, scnscene

Currently I'm working on AR Based project which has the functionality of duplicating the AR Object , the problem Im having is when i use .clone() method to clone SCNNode ... it creates same instances and when i change name of duplicated SCNNode , it change name of all nodes .. How can i clone the SCNNode with having different name,modelName etc properties ?

Basically i want specific property of every cloned Virtual Object to delete the object ..

**Code for placing Object**

```
    func placeVirtualObject(_ virtualObject: VirtualObject) {
    guard let cameraTransform = session.currentFrame?.camera.transform,
        let focusSquarePosition = focusSquare.lastPosition else {
        statusViewController.showMessage("CANNOT PLACE OBJECT\nTry moving left or right.")
        return
    }
    Api.Params.selectedModel = virtualObject
    virtualObject.name = String(Api.Params.inputPreviewId)
    virtualObject.scale = SCNVector3Make(0.01, 0.01, 0.01)

    virtualObject.setPosition(focusSquarePosition, relativeTo: cameraTransform, smoothMovement: false)
    updateQueue.async {
        self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(virtualObject)
    }
}
```

**for duplicating node**

```
        func placeDuplicateVirtualObject(_ virtualObject: VirtualObject) {
        guard let cameraTransform = session.currentFrame?.camera.transform,
            let focusSquarePosition = focusSquare.lastPosition else {
            statusViewController.showMessage("CANNOT PLACE OBJECT\nTry moving left or right.")
            return
        }
        Api.Params.selectedModel = virtualObject
        let duplicate = virtualObject.clone()
        
        duplicate.name = String(Api.Params.inputPreviewId)
        
        duplicate.scale = SCNVector3Make(0.01, 0.01, 0.01)

        duplicate.setPosition(focusSquarePosition, relativeTo: cameraTransform, smoothMovement: false)
        updateQueue.async {
            self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(duplicate)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What problem are you really trying to solve? Is this a performance issue? Something else?

Comment: @HalMueller , I want to delete VirtualObject by its name (or any unique property) , now the problem is that whenever i duplicate the VirtualObject , it clones with the same reference and when i change its name , it changes in all the VirtualObject from Parent to child because of the same reference